# MOSFETs and Chokes on Computer Motherboards

Tags: mosfet, circuit-design, cpu, motherboard, choke

There is a lot of conflicting information on the internet about what role these play in CPU power delivery.

A lot of people online say that having more MOSFETs and chokes results in cleaner power delivery to the CPU, thus allowing it to operate better, but looking at examples of many high-end and low end motherboards is showing me that fewer MOSFETs and chokes are present on either lower-end boards or boards that support processors with a lower TDP.

What do they do, and what advantage does an abundance of these components actually offer? Also, am I understanding correctly that lower power processors generally require less of them?

Comment: Sounds like a lot of people online don't have a clue what they're talking about.

Comment: mother boards are already feed with DC supply the power converters (MOSFET/ CHOKE) placed in the board are used where they are required not just for the filter, e.g. converting 3.3V to 1.2 V, etc.

Comment: Poly-phase buck converters reduce the stored energy, ripple current and cost of each switch, inductor and cap significantly and reduce the overall ripple significantly as well as increase the bandwidth using lower switching frequency and thus better high speed step load regulation.  I can see 15 phases on the Intel FIVR schematic in spec.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those components are part of a [buck converter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buck_converter), which is used to reduce a 12V supply from the PSU to around 1.2V for the CPU (Vcore).

Most motherboards use a multiphase buck converter, which has multiple buck converters running in a cycle to provide a more stable supply for the CPU. More phases can make for a more stable input, especially for a higher TDP processor; each set of MOSFET and inductor (choke) you see makes up one phase.

What does complicate matters a bit is that some Intel processors (in particular, the Haswell and Broadwell generations) relocated some of the work of voltage regulation to the CPU itself, by integrating tiny inductors into the CPU package. Intel referred to this as the FIVR, or [Fully Integrated Voltage Regulator](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/271416878_FIVR_-_Fully_integrated_voltage_regulators_on_4th_generation_IntelR_Core_SoCs). This caused motherboards for these CPU generations to contain fewer visible power-regulating parts.

Comment: Thank you, that answered my question and went a bit beyond it to help me understand the mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

> The influences of PolyPhase techniques on the load transient performance are numerous.

First, the reduced output ripple voltage allows more room for voltage variations
during the load transient because the ripple voltage will
consume a smaller portion of the total error budget. With
the same number of capacitors on the output terminals of
the power supply, the sum of the overshoot and undershoot can be reduced dramatically.

Second, the reduced
ripple current allows the use of lower value inductors. This
speeds up the output current slew rate of the power
supply.

**Consequently, PolyPhase helps improve the load
transient performance of the power supply.**

Ref [Linear Technology](http://www.linear.com/docs/4166)